# How to remove all pie menus in Blender 2.8?

Tags: pie-menu

I like Blender 2.79 - why? Blender 2.79 did not have pie menus shoved EVERYWHERE. In 2.79, there was an option to enable and *disable* them (emphasis on the disable). I find pie menus exceedingly annoying. (Example: out of habit, I instinctively press Z to toggle to wireframe mode. Instead of getting to wireframe mode, I get this weird pie thing in my face). No one likes pie in their face. I can not find an option anywhere to disable the pie menus in Blender 2.8. Is it possible to disable them in Blender 2.8, or is this a *helpful* feature we are stuck with?

Comment: I found the pie menus quite a shock as well, but once you realise that they are supposed to be *gestural*, they quickly make a lot of sense. You hold Z to bring up the display mode menu, flick the mouse towards the selection you want, and release Z. After only a few tries your muscle memory will take over and you'll find they integrate into your flow quite well. Trust the blender crew! Be open to new ideas! That's what blender is all about!

Comment: A more helpful answer is to change the keymapping to Blender 27X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to completely remove pie menus (without building your own version) but you can get closer.

Start by disabling *Tab for Pie Menu.* That will get you back the familiar tab usage.

Next I'd recommend enabling *Pie Menu On Drag*. That setting makes some buttons (like <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd> and others do double duty. Simply pressing them invokes a normal event, but pressing them and moving the mouse makes a pie menu popup).

Now start changing the keybinding in the keymap here is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> **Snapping**. Set the identifier to "*wm.call_menu*" and the name to "*VIEW3D_MT_snap*". Old snapping menu is back.

[image: Snapping Shift S]

Comment: well that is at least a start. This is not a **thanks :)** comment.